# regexp: exclude partial words from the longer word

Tags: regex

I have created an regular expression which looks for email addresses to my domain fred.com that begin with "ar" as follows:

```
(^ar.*)+(@fred\.com$)
```

so all email addresses that look like `ar*@fred.com` will get matched.
I think the above code is correct and will achieve that.

BUT, I want to exclude the address arthur@fred.com so the resulting match will be FALSE

i.e. I want `ar*@fred.com` AND NOT `arthur@fred.com`

How do I do this?

Comment: Which programming language or text editor are you using?

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately the app I'm reads this as incorrect syntax

Comment: I'm in Googles Routing set-up in their G-Suite / mail app.  It asks for (regex) pattern recognition

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your initial regex can be simplified to:

```
^(ar.*)@fred.com$
```

which will now match all emails in the form of `ar*@fred.com`

To answer your question: This is a possible solution:

```
^(ar(?!(?:thur|bla)@).*)@fred.com$
```

Which matches everything but `arthur@fred.com` and `arbla@fred.com` and has everything before the @ in the capture-group

[See here](http://regexr.com/3f41c) for some examples

Comment: looks promising but the engine Im in says incorrect syntax

Comment: @Arthur you can try removing this stuff: remove the capture group (outer most parenthesis; you won't need it anyway); remove ^ and $ (don't know if you need them for pattern matching in your case); remove the ?: part in the inner most part.    You can also try to put / before and after the expression (javascript does that - looks like /regex/) and escaping the @ sign (very unlikely to be the problem;  \@)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Michael Ritter, your regex can be simplified.

You have to use the "subpattern property" (Don't know the exact term) -> ?!

Test made in PHP :

```
<?
$regex = '/^(ar(?!thur@fred.com$)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*?)@fred.com$/';
// Or this one should do the trick, but it is a way more permissive
//$regex = '/^ar(((?!thur@fred.com$).*?)[^^@])?@fred.com$/';
foreach(array('arthur@fred.com', 'arthu@fred.com', 'arthur^@fred.com', 'arthu@@fred.com', 'aramis@fred.com', 'arthurad@fred.com', 'ar@fred.com') as $email){
    echo $email . ' => ' . (preg_match($regex, $email) ? 'ALLOW' : 'DENY') . "\n";
}
?>
```

This outputs :

```
C:\Users\rbala\php\tools>..\php\php5.2.10\php.exe regexNot.php
arthur@fred.com => DENY
arthu@fred.com => ALLOW
arthur^@fred.com => DENY
arthu@@fred.com => DENY
aramis@fred.com => ALLOW
arthurad@fred.com => ALLOW
ar@fred.com => ALLOW
```

- The first regex forces you to tell the chars you want
- For the second one forces you to tell the chars you don't want [^^@] => NOT ^@ before @

I don't see other ways with regex only.

@TaoStyle : Thx for the tip. I can't comment your posts...
Your regex match the following patterns :

```
arthur^@fred.com => ALLOW
arthu@@fred.com => ALLOW
```

Comment: The regex you suggest would wrongly return as FALSE email like `arthurad@fred.com`, since the `.*` is between the expression arthur and `@`. I was playing with the same thought process, but haven't figured out, yet, how to get around this limitation.

Comment: @TaoStyle : Your totally right !!! I edit as soon as answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This could match your needs:

```
^(ar(?!thur@fred.com$).*?)@fred.com$
```

[Here's an example](https://regex101.com/r/g79nO6/4)

It would refuse arthur@fred.com, but would accept other variants like:

- arduino@fred.com
- armadillo@fred.com
- art@fred.com
- arthurad@fred.com